# How to show CJK lang in the console at the same time?

Tags: windows-7, console

What I've tried:

- Save both CJK and ASCII characters in the file encoded with UTF-8
- chcp 65001
- type file.txt

It just printed out garbage !

How to show  CJK lang in the console at the same time like the picture below?

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/14/KoreanDOSPrompt.png))</sub>

(from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms)

**Related: [Why sometimes the codepage is invalid in console?](https://superuser.com/questions/692709/why-sometimes-the-codepage-is-invalid-in-console)**

**My system envir.:**

Windows7 + System loacle: Taiwan + Language pack: English

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to choose TrueType font in the console (Consolas or Lucida Console). They must be available after switching to 65001 codepage.

[image: Standard console]

Or, you may try alternative terminals. ConEmu for example (I'm the author).

[image: ConEmu]

Comment: Great answer. I solved the problem by the means you provided.

Comment: PS. Is it able to change input method (輸入法) into Chinese, Japanese, or etc while the codepage is UTF-8 (65001) in console?

Comment: ConEmu? Yes, IME is always available.

Comment: How about CMD.exe?