# How do i show characters from different languages in cmd at the same time?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, fonts, console

Suppose I want be able to dislpay this string in cmd at the same time:

```
██ অ আ কা কি ক अ आ इ ई 国 会 这 来 对 ܬ‎, ܫ‎, ܪ‎, ܩ‎, ܨ‎, ܦ
```

But, it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKuSP.png) when the font is set to Lucida Console‎.
When i set the font to something that has Chinese characters in it, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGNKP.png), and as you can see its not able to display the Bengali or Hindi characters cause they aren't present in these fonts.

CMD is really hard to get working right with fonts. It only supports Monospace fonts. It can't support Open Type Fonts as far as I am aware. And its really hard to find a font that is true type, is monospace and is multilingual at the same time.

How should I go about this? Is there some workaround to showing different languages that are present in different font files? Should I use something other than cmd altogether?

If you're wondering why I want to do this, I'm writing an application that involves showing random unicode characters in the command prompt.

My sys enviroment: Windows 10, and codepage: 65001

Comment: another user has a very similar problem: https://superuser.com/questions/692987/how-to-show-cjk-lang-in-the-console-at-the-same-time , but they have different requirements altogether, and that isn't really a solution to my problem.

Comment: Cross-site apparent duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938639/monospace-unicode-font

Comment: Use the [chcp command](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) to change the code-page to UTF8: `chcp 65001`.

Comment: @harrymc yeah I already have my code-page in UTF8, I mentioned that in my post

Comment: @JeffZeitlin , it seems that most of those fonts aren't supported on cmd, they just don't appear in the fonts page when I download it. I guess I will just switch to something other than cmd, until it gets better font support. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not managed to make your example string display correctly, neither
on CMD nor on PowerShell. Not even after executing `chcp 65001`.

However, this did half-work on the Windows Terminal: When entering
an `echo` command of the string, the command itself was badly displayed,
but the string was then echoed correctly, although each character was
displayed on a separate line:

[image]

My conclusion is that full Unicode support is just not available
in the Windows consoles.

Alternate consoles work better, especially ones that are forked from
the Linux bash. For example, here is the output for the `echo`
command on [cmder](https://cmder.net/):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for clearing the confusion. I will now move on to another terminal. Although, is it possible to get this working with a font that contains all unicode characters? This definitely seems to happen because most fonts don't contain all those characters at the same time, and there are very few multilingual fonts that work on cmd